# How to make content_filter work for only my domain

Tags: postfix

I have a simple content_filter and attached it successfully to Postfix. However for any e-mail coming to Postfix it calls this filter. However I only want this filter to be called when e-mail is coming to my server (to:name@mydomain). For mails to be relayed through my server to other servers (to:name@otherdomain), I dont want my filter to be called.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead using `content_filter` globally in **main.cf**, you can turn on content filtering with an [access(5)](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) table rule with FILTER feature. See [here](http://www.postfix.org/FILTER_README.html#dynamic_filter) for further info.

In your `smtpd_*_restriction` (smtpd_recipient_restriction for example) place this line

```
check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/mycontentfilter
```

In `/etc/postfix/mycontentfilter` place

```
example.com    FILTER foo:bar
```

You can find another example in [amavisd documentation](http://www.ijs.si/software/amavisd/README.postfix.html#filter_by_recipient).